# Character too large for enclosing character literal type вылетает ошибка при использовании русского символа/

Tags: c++, c, строки, unicode, char

> Я столкнулся с проблемой при сравнении символов вылетает ошибка и не совсем понятно как её решить/

```
int main(){
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    person* persPtr [ 100 ];
    int n = 0;
    char choice;
    do
    {
        persPtr [ n ] = new person;
        persPtr [ n ]->setName ( );
        n++;
        cout << "Продолжаем ввод (д/н)?";
        cin >> choice;
    }
```

```
    while ( choice == 'д' ); // В єтот момент вылетает ошибка Character too large for enclosing character literal type
```

}

Comment: Видимо, текст программы у вас в utf-8 или иной многобайтной кодировке... В которой `'д'` - ну никак не один `char`.

Comment: Покажите, какую у вас возвращает кодировку консоли. `char * code = setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru"); std::cout<<"code = "<< code << std::endl;` Можно в другой пустой программе. И можно будет поговорить.

Comment: AlexGlebe, в итоге вышло code = ru

Comment: неможет быть. попробуйте так : `char * code = setlocale(LC_ALL, "");`

Comment: AlexGlebe, code = Russian_Russia.1251

Comment: Значит в редакторе укажите кодировку CP1251. Вместо UTF-8